# which is the best option for making mysql play well with gevent in a django app

Tags: python, mysql, django, gevent, gunicorn

I have a django app running on gunicorn with mysql as the database. I have added gevent in order to deal with multiple file uploads, but I am not sure what is my best driver option for making gevent play well with a mysql database.

(Please note the database already contains a large amount of data, so moving to postgres is an unattractive option)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [Projects Using Gevent](http://code.google.com/p/gevent/wiki/ProjectsUsingGevent)?

**Edit**: According to above page gevent-MySQL is no longer supported. That makes [ultramysql](https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql) the only viable option.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the suggestion. The only problem with ultramysql is there doesn't seem to be much in the way of documentation for integration and use in projects.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of a disadvantage. gevent itself is still relatively new in the Python world. Also read somewhere that ultramysql is not really working with major libraries (SQLAlchemy, probably Django ORM) yet.

Comment: Thanks, I voted your anser up, but I will leave the question open on the off change there is an answer out there

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use pymysql since it can be monkey-patched. I haven't used it myself yet, but here's a YouTube video of a presentation called "Django on Gevent" by Cody Soyland at DjangoCon earlier this year: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nocGRsytBkk

Pymysql can be found here: https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL